# oracle19c - Port 1521 open on remote VM and visible in netstat, but cannot ping with telnet

Tags: networking, centos7, google-cloud-platform, oracle, firewalld

I am running into some issues while trying to access a remove oracle db 19.3. The VM (CentOS 7) is located inside GCP Cloud and I can ping it on other ports (22), but i cannot connect to the database using sqldeveloper or even ping port 1521 with telnet.

The firewall is disabled and the lsnrctl status is up, but i'm a bit worried about the output:

```
LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 30-MAR-2023 18:13:07

Copyright (c) 1991, 2019, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                30-MAR-2023 16:54:43
Uptime                    0 days 1 hr. 18 min. 24 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /oracle/product/19.3/db_home/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /oracle/diag/tnslsnr/oracle-19c/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=oracle-19c.c.enhanced-tuner-382015.internal)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "CDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "CDBXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "f810a6809fc55a12e0530300840a2cc0" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "f810a75fde6b5b22e0530300840a8ce6" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orcl" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "pdb2" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Here is the output for the netstat -tlpn | grep 1521:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::1521                 :::*                    LISTEN      1298/tnslsnr
```

Also, the 3 files *.ora files were not added from the start inside $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin/, so i've added them from the 'samples/', but I think most of them are empty/commented out.

I've also tried reenabling firewalld service and starting it, adding a firewall exception for the port, and also adding a firewall exception in GCP, but still cannot make it happen.

Please let me know what else I am missing. Thanks!

Comment: Can you `telnet ::1 1521` **and** `telnet 127.0.0.1 1521` from inside the server? Does a `tcpdump -n -iany port 1521` show any incoming packets whenever you attempt to connect from outside?

Comment: Also `tnsping` (on local machine) can help

Comment: ```telnet ::1 1521
Trying ::1...
Connected to ::1.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Comment: ```telnet 127.0.0.1 1521
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.```